# progress bar in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created token in tkinter window which changes the value each 10 seconds. I want to improve it and add progress bar. I know about ready libraries, but I want to use my personal code. My question is how to slow down the loop so the current value will be conveyed to string variable and after one second another value according to loop progress etc. My code just needs this "stopper". I could use 10 different functions and just triger after() but it doesn't look good and also my program crashes after a while.

```
def count(self):
        k =[" l", " l", " l"," l"," l"," l"," l"," l"," l"," l"]
        for x in range(9,0,-1):
                self.test_var.set(k[x]*x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Here is a generalized method, which should give the idea of how to solve this problem. It contains all necessary parts, but it must be implemented into right places of your code.

To make sure your tkinter window wouldn't freeze during the update phase, you have to do the progress bar updating in another thread.

To call the method repeatedly after a certain time you can use `time.sleep()` method and a recursive method to call itself again and again.

```
import threading
import time


def change_progressbar(bar):
    # If there is more progress bar points to display, then do it
    if bar > 0:
        print(bar * ' l')  # Change your var here instead of printing
        time.sleep(10) # Wait 10 seconds
        change_progressbar(bar - 1) # Call itself again with one less point in a progress bar

# Let's call a method in new thread, with argument bar=10, which
# defines how many progress bar points there will be at start.
progressbar_thread = threading.Thread(target=change_progressbar, args=[10])
progressbar_thread.start()

# Output:  
# l l l l l l l l l l
# l l l l l l l l l
# l l l l l l l l
# l l l l l l l
# l l l l l l
# l l l l l
# l l l l
# l l l
# l l
# l
```

Comment: Basically I want to display 10 things at the begining and then substract one each second. As I guess I need to begin with args[] set to 10 and then change progress in def.count to -= " l". Is that correct ?

Comment: @ledinos1 Yes, the idea is right, but you can't subtract string ffom string straightly. I will also update the answer ASAP.

Comment: @ledinos1 I provided an example in reversed mode also. Of course, there are many different ways to format your progress bar string, but this time I stayed with your version with variable k as a list.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have to analize your code to understand it (I'm the beginner) and will let you now if worked soon

Comment: I tried your code and maybe I did something wrong but it did not work for me. I copied the content straight to my visual studio.

Comment: @ledinos1 I don't see your whole code, so it might not fit straight into your code. Did it give any specific errors or maybe you could reveal more of your code.

Comment: @ledinos1 i also added a more generalized version, which contains all necessary parts, but need to be added to right places in your code.

Comment: ok, seems good to me now. As you have preasumed before - yes i have a class which is a TopLevel for another master class so I have to adjust everything now. Threading is completly new thing for me in python, so apologizes for bothering you and hence stupid questions.

Comment: @ledinos1 Nothing to apologize for, I would not say that threading is such a basic knowledge.

Comment: Ok i have figured it out and adjusted succesfully to my code. Thanks a lot, I've learnt something new ! :)

Answer (score -1):

The "stopper" you are looking for is time.sleep()

The sleep function needs one argument, which is the amount of seconds to wait. 
This can also be a float like 0.5

You use it like this:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("One second has passed")
```

This code will print something every second.

Comment: @ledinos1 Yes, thats because it puts the loop your tkinter window is running to sleep. That is why you have to do this in another thread.